# Count consecutive prior dates per group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My sample data.frame (date format d/m/y), recording the dates a customer was active:

```
customer    date 
1           10/1/20
1           9/1/20 
1           6/1/20
2           10/1/20
2           8/1/20
2           7/1/20
2           6/1/20
```

I would like to make a column "n_consecutive_days" like so:

```
customer    date    n_consecutive_days
1           10/1/20  2
1           9/1/20   1
1           6/1/20   N/A
2           10/1/20  1
2           8/1/20   3
2           7/1/20   2
2           6/1/20   N/A
```

The new column counts the number of previous consecutive dates per customer. I would like the customer's first date to be N/A as it makes no sense to talk about previous consecutive days if it is the first one.

Any help would be appreciated. I can calculate the difference between dates, but not the number of consecutive days as desired.

Comment: Why is there an extra row in  your desired output?

Comment: I don't quite see how the `n_consecutive_days` column is supposed to be computed... What's the difference between `N/A` and `0`? Why are there no entries of `1`?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery, looks like it is date format `"%e/%m/%y"` but I cannot be 100% sure without confirmation from OP

Comment: @Andrew That's quite possible -- but I'm still confused about why `N/A` is ever used and why `1` isn't...

Comment: I guess because you can't have one consecutive day! The minimum you can have, by definition, is 2. You can have zero (a single lonely day) or NA (the very first day of the group). It makes sense to me.

Comment: Hi guys, so date format is d/m/y. I would like N/A due to there not being a previous date for that customer.

Comment: @Edward It makes it discontinuous though, right? If I go in on four consecutive days, then those days are to be marked 0, 2, 3, 4? It doesn't sit right with me and will create some tiny unnecessary headache to code up, but if it makes sense to the OP then it's fine.

Comment: Sorry guys I will just simplify this, I will accept an answer that gives 1, 2, 3, 4 to avoid headaches. But yes @Edward I would agree that you cannot have 1 consecutive day.

Comment: It's easy to do. Make it 0 or 1 for a lonely day, whatever is easier to code. Then change it to whatever you want at the end (`1 -> 0` or `0 -> 1`). No big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(customer, idx = cumsum(as.integer(c(0, diff(as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%y')))) != -1)) %>%
  mutate(n_consecutive_days = rev(sequence(n()))) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(customer) %>%
  mutate(n_consecutive_days = replace(n_consecutive_days, row_number() == n(), NA), idx = NULL)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   customer [2]
  customer date    n_consecutive_days
     <int> <fct>                <int>
1        1 10/1/20                  2
2        1 9/1/20                   1
3        1 6/1/20                  NA
4        2 10/1/20                  1
5        2 8/1/20                   3
6        2 7/1/20                   2
7        2 6/1/20                  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
#ensure that data is sorted by customer and reverse chronological
setorder(DT, customer, -date)

#group by customer and consecutive dates and then create the sequence
DT[, ncd := .N:1L, .(customer, cumsum(c(0L, diff(date)!=-1L)))]

#set the first date in each customer to NA
DT[DT[, .I[.N], customer]$V1, ncd := NA]
```

output:

```
   customer       date ncd
1:        1 2020-01-10   2
2:        1 2020-01-09   1
3:        1 2020-01-06  NA
4:        2 2020-01-10   1
5:        2 2020-01-08   3
6:        2 2020-01-07   2
7:        2 2020-01-06  NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("customer    date 
1           10/1/20
1           9/1/20 
1           6/1/20
2           10/1/20
2           8/1/20
2           7/1/20
2           6/1/20")
DT[, date := as.IDate(date, format="%d/%m/%y")]
```